# Symfony 1.2 Output buffering off in php-cli ini but commande line scripts are shown at the end

Tags: php, symfony, output-buffering, symfony-1.2

I'm working on symfony 1.2 and we have changed the server recently.

Since we have migrated on our new servers, the output buffering seems to be active on the php command line tool.

But if I check the *settings of the `php.ini` of `php-cli` it's disabled.*

I made some tests, and in the symfony task when I write something in the "configure" method, the text is shown directly ( so it is correct ).

But once we are in the `"execute"` method, the text is not shown anymore, I have to wait the end of the script to see the text displayed.

It is very annoying for long tasks where I want to see what's happening line by line.

I don't understand why symfony enable a pseudo-output buffering by itself

if I echo the `ini_get('output_buffering')`, it display 0. so...

I don't know what is the settings difference between my old servers and the new ones that produce this unexpected problem.

Comment: Got the same problem. Would be interested in a solution too.